# Preparation of isotopic CO2 standards from Sn-encapsulated CaCO3

Tags: analytical-chemistry, elemental-analysis

I wish to prepare isotopic CO2 gas standards for highly 13C enriched CO2. The CO2 concentrations will be ~1000 ppm, with the balance either N2 or zero air.

My plan is as follows:

1. Encapsulate labeled CaCO3 in normal 5x9mm tin capsules (varying quantities of Ca<sup>12</sup>CO3 and Ca<sup>13</sup>CO3.)
2. Place these tin capsules in a borosilicate tube in-line between the balance gas tank and the storage vessel, with quartz wool packed on each side.

3.Thermally decompose the CaCO3 with a bunsen burner, and then very slowly increase the pressure on the balance gas regulator to sweep the CO2 into the storage vessel (max pressure 7 bar, allowing plenty of time for the tube to cool).

The reason why I want to use tin capsules is that I don't want the chance of CaCO3 powder getting stuck on any surfaces while putting it in the tube, as it's crucial that all of the weighed CaCO3 be decomposed in order to arrive at the right isotopic composition. The quartz wool is to prevent any reacted CaO from being swept into the storage vessel.

I have two questions:
Is the tin going to mess in any way with the release of CO2 from the CaCO3, either using zero air or N2 as the balance gas?
Can you think of anything that could go wrong with this setup?

Comment: I guess zero air is CO2 free air,or eventually synthetic air.

Comment: Do you know that you may purchase analytical standards like "normal" $\ce{CO2}$ gas, $\ce{C^{18}O2}$, $\ce{^{13}C^{18}O2}$, $\ce{^{13}C^{17}O2}$, $\ce{^{13}CO2}$, $\ce{^{12}CO2}$, $\ce{^{13}C^{16}O2}$,$\ce{C^{17}O2}$ from sources *like* [SigmaAldrich](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/search/co2?focus=products&page=1&perPage=30&sort=relevance&term=CO2&type=product)? It may be much less hassle for you to purchase such a gas of guaranteed quality in a small pressurized cylinder from a source with the *savoir faire* than to set up such an experiment and to train yourself.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to heat some CaCO3 to a temperature where it is decomposed. At this temperature, the glas will be nearly liquid. Don't you think that some gas may leak through a hole in the molten glass ?

Comment: Poutnik - Yes, zero air is zero CO2, zero hydrocarbon air.
Buttonwood - Yes, I do know that. I got a set of isotope calibration gases quoted out for me by Airgas (3 in air, 3 in N2), enough for approx a year of my work. It was >$12k. Maurice - Thermal decomposition of CaCO3 occurs at ~800C, borosilicate melts at ~1600C, so no, I'm not too worried. Thermal decomposition of CaCO3 in a test tube is a classic high school chemistry experiment.